# Drupal 7 Views - same setting but different display

Tags: drupal-7

I have 2 Drupal 7 Views, let's name it block_1 and block_2. They both ahve the same exact setting but the output they both give is different? Why is it like that? Any clue? FYI, I tried clear cache but also nothing happened. The export is as below:

```
/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Side events';
$handler->display->display_options['use_ajax'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['pure_distinct'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'better_exposed_filters';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['bef'] = array(
  'general' => array(
    'allow_secondary' => 0,
    'secondary_label' => 'Advanced options',
    'collapsible_label' => NULL,
    'combine_rewrite' => NULL,
    'reset_label' => NULL,
  ),
  'flagged' => array(
    'bef_format' => 'bef',
    'more_options' => array(
      'bef_select_all_none' => FALSE,
      'bef_collapsible' => 0,
      'is_secondary' => 0,
      'any_label' => 'All',
      'bef_filter_description' => '',
      'tokens' => array(
        'available' => array(
          0 => 'global_types',
          'secondary_label' => NULL,
          'collapsible_label' => NULL,
          'combine_rewrite' => NULL,
          'reset_label' => NULL,
        ),
        'secondary_label' => NULL,
        'collapsible_label' => NULL,
        'combine_rewrite' => NULL,
        'reset_label' => NULL,
      ),
      'rewrite' => array(
        'filter_rewrite_values' => '0|',
        'secondary_label' => NULL,
        'collapsible_label' => NULL,
        'combine_rewrite' => NULL,
        'reset_label' => NULL,
      ),
      'secondary_label' => NULL,
      'collapsible_label' => NULL,
      'combine_rewrite' => NULL,
      'reset_label' => NULL,
    ),
    'secondary_label' => NULL,
    'collapsible_label' => NULL,
    'combine_rewrite' => NULL,
    'reset_label' => NULL,
  ),
  'secondary_label' => NULL,
  'collapsible_label' => NULL,
  'combine_rewrite' => NULL,
  'reset_label' => NULL,
);
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['input_required'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['text_input_required_format'] = 'plain_text';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class'] = 'side-event-row date-[field_side_event_date_1]';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['default_field_elements'] = FALSE;
/* Relationship: Entity Reference: Referencing entity */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['id'] = 'reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['field'] = 'reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['label'] = 'ref';
/* Relationship: Flags: side_event_favourite */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['id'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['field'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['label'] = 'favourited';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['required'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['flag'] = 'side_event_favourite';
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'date_short',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_remaining_days' => 0,
  'show_repeat_rule' => 'show',
  'conditions' => array(
    0 => array(
      'condition' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
/* Sort criterion: MIN(Content: Date (field_side_event_date)) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['group_type'] = 'min';
/* Contextual filter: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['default_argument_type'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'side_events' => 'side_events',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type (field_side_event_type) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['id'] = 'field_side_event_type_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['field'] = 'field_side_event_type_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['value'] = array(
  111 => '111',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['type'] = 'select';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['vocabulary'] = 'event_type';


/* Display: Scheduled side events */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Scheduled side events', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['group_by'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['grouping'] = array(
  0 => array(
    'field' => 'field_side_event_date',
    'rendered' => 0,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class'] = 'side-event-row date-[field_side_event_date_1] [flagged]';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['uses_fields'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'date_short',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_remaining_days' => 0,
  'show_repeat_rule' => 'show',
  'conditions' => array(
    0 => array(
      'condition' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'privatemsg_current_day',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_remaining_days' => 0,
  'show_repeat_rule' => 'show',
  'conditions' => array(
    0 => array(
      'condition' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
/* Field: Flags: Flagged */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['id'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['table'] = 'flagging';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['field'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['type'] = 'custom';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['type_custom_true'] = 'favourited';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['type_custom_false'] = 'not-favourited';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['not'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['sorts'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Date (field_side_event_date) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['group_type'] = 'min';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Start hour (field_side_event_start_hour) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_start_hour_value']['id'] = 'field_side_event_start_hour_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_start_hour_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_start_hour';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_start_hour_value']['field'] = 'field_side_event_start_hour_value';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'side_events' => 'side_events',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type (field_side_event_type) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['id'] = 'field_side_event_type_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['field'] = 'field_side_event_type_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['value'] = array(
  112 => '112',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['type'] = 'select';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['vocabulary'] = 'event_type';

/* Display: Scheduled attachment */
$handler = $view->new_display('attachment', 'Scheduled attachment', 'attachment_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['css_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['css_class'] = 'view-side-events-tabs';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['query'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class'] = 'side-event-row-tab date-[field_side_event_date_1]';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['default_field_elements'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['relationships'] = FALSE;
/* Relationship: Entity Reference: Referencing entity */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['id'] = 'reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['field'] = 'reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['label'] = 'ref';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'date_short',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_remaining_days' => 0,
  'show_repeat_rule' => 'show',
  'conditions' => array(
    0 => array(
      'condition' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'privatemsg_current_day',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_remaining_days' => 0,
  'show_repeat_rule' => 'show',
  'conditions' => array(
    0 => array(
      'condition' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['sorts'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: MIN(Content: Date (field_side_event_date)) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['group_type'] = 'min';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'side_events' => 'side_events',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type (field_side_event_type) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['id'] = 'field_side_event_type_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['field'] = 'field_side_event_type_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['value'] = array(
  112 => '112',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['type'] = 'select';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_side_event_type_tid']['vocabulary'] = 'event_type';
$handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(
  'block_old_1' => 'block_old_1',
  'default' => 0,
  'side_events' => 0,
  'block_4' => 0,
  'block_2' => 0,
);

/* Display: On demand side events */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'On demand side events', 'side_events');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['group_by'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class'] = 'side-event-row date-[field_side_event_date_1]';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['uses_fields'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'entity';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'date_short',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_remaining_days' => 0,
  'show_repeat_rule' => 'show',
  'conditions' => array(
    0 => array(
      'condition' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
/* Field: Content: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_side_event_date_1']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'privatemsg_current_day',
  'fromto' => 'both',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_remaining_days' => 0,
  'show_repeat_rule' => 'show',
  'conditions' => array(
    0 => array(
      'condition' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
/* Field: Flags: Flagged */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['id'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['table'] = 'flagging';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['field'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['type'] = 'custom';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['type_custom_true'] = 'favourited';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['type_custom_false'] = 'not-favourited';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['flagged']['not'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['sorts'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Date (field_side_event_date) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['id'] = 'field_side_event_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_date';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['field'] = 'field_side_event_date_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_date_value']['group_type'] = 'min';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Start hour (field_side_event_start_hour) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_start_hour_value']['id'] = 'field_side_event_start_hour_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_start_hour_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_side_event_start_hour';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_side_event_start_hour_value']['field'] = 'field_side_event_start_hour_value';

/* Display: On demand attachment */
$handler = $view->new_display('attachment', 'On demand attachment', 'attachment_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['relationships'] = FALSE;
/* Relationship: Entity Reference: Referencing entity */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['id'] = 'reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['field'] = 'reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_event_side_events_ref_node']['label'] = 'ref';
$handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(
  'side_events' => 'side_events',
  'default' => 0,
  'side_events_old' => 0,
  'block_4' => 0,
  'block_1' => 0,
  'block_2' => 0,
);
```

The 4 views should be exactly same is:

```
  t('On demand attachment'),
  t('Scheduled side events'),
  t('Scheduled attachment'),
  t('On demand side events'),
```

Only the results, which is filtered by type is different

Comment: What’s different? Fields? Location of output? What’s the display set for both? There are so many areas under settings and perhaps u overlooked something !

Comment: I presume these views are displayed as blocks. Are the block visibility settings relevant the view content? i.e. authorized vs. anonymous users... If you can export the view and block code and share here, we can do better than guess-work

Answer (score 1):

Export your views Display and compare them with each other. certainly, there are some differences which make different result.

at the `admin/structure/views`

With getting help with  following  image you will get how to export a view.

[image]

Comment: @CloudSeph https://www.diffchecker.com/yiBRvETP . you can see one of your blocks display has different filters.